# Purpose of defining an Annotation inside an Annotation in Java

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm a Java developer going through the code base at the company I work for trying to look for advanced language syntax I'm unfamiliar with. I stumbled across a folder of constraint annotations that all contain annotation definitions within themselves like follows...

```
@Constraint(validatedBy=MyValidator.class)
@Target(FIELD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)    
@Documented
public @interface FirstAnnotation{ 
    Class<?>[] groups() default{};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
    String message() default "Default message";

    @Target({FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE})
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @Documented
    @interface List {
        FirstAnnotation[] value();
    }
}
```

Can someone enlighten me as to the purpose of this and how it would be exercised? I get that it is a list of the FirstAnnotation as the value, but not sure what a use case for this would be and how you could use the List annotation. I'm also curious if someone could shine a light on why the groups(), payload(), and message() are required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a static member, which means you can use this:

```
@FirstAnnotation.List({
    @FirstAnnotation(...),
    @FirstAnnotation(...)
})
private MyType myField;
```

You can make this even easier by annotating `FirstAnnotation` with `@Repeatable(FirstAnnotation.List.class)`. That way, you can omit the explicit list:

```
@FirstAnnotation(...)
@FirstAnnotation(...)
private MyType myField;
```

As for these three fields, see https://javaee.github.io/tutorial/bean-validation-advanced001.html and https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.1/reference/en-US/html/validator-customconstraints.html.

Comment: Interesting, I added the '@Repeatable' annotation. I had to ensure that the '@Target' annotation of FirstAnnotation included ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE. Presumably, since there will now be annotations on top of annotations. I'll have to look up some use cases for why one would want to repeat the same annotation. Thx @RobSpoor